# Eclipse machine dependent variable?

Tags: android, eclipse, variables, location

I am working on a eclipse android projekt on two different machines (home and work)

Everytime I switch home to work and vice versa, I replace the project folder in its current location with the newest version I have been working on in my previous location and continue working.

Now each time I do that I also have to adjust my Constants source file because some variables in the app are different depending on whether I am at work or at home (these are preset debug variables like IP address for webserver that I hardcode to ensure a fast workflow).

Question: Can I prevent the adjusting of the source file by storing these preset variables somewhere else (eclipse settings or external text file) so that they are not carried over from my previous location? How would I go about setting that up?